# Laravel pivot table record check and also check in main table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I creating a library management project in my village library.

I have three tables.

```
books
---------
id
title
copies

borrowers
---------
id
name

borrows
---------
id
cleared
book_id
borrower_id
```

I joined the borrower table and books table in has one relation to borrows table.

my problem is if book copies 2 available. 
1 borrowed by some user another one copy available in a library.
I am trying to get if one copy available in a library then show to lend view.

this is my code.

```
    $books = Book::doesnthave('borrows', 'or', function($query) {
        $query->where('cleared', '=', '0');
       })->get();
    return AllBookResource::collection($books);
```

I want to get lent cleared books or book not cleared if one copy is available.

Answer (score 0):

I would change your approach in how you handle the copies.

**Solution**

Make another table for the copies you have, this way, it will be easier for you to make changes, like add the edition of the book, the year it was printed, and it will be easier to see if it has a copy available to be borrowed.

Comment: nice idea bro i will try

Answer (score 0):

You could check for the count of borrowed books that have not been cleared and only return the books where the copies value is higher than it.

```
$books = Book::withCount('borrows', 'or', function($query) {
    $query->where('cleared', '=', '0');
   })
     ->whereColumn('borrows_count', '<', 'books.copies')
     ->get();
return AllBookResource::collection($books);
```

Note that the whereColumn function is only available on laravel 5 and upwards.

Comment: bro I tried but error returned Unknown column 'borrows_count'

Comment: Please don't call me bro. That's weird and should not happen. The docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#Counting-Related-Models explain it this way and I've seen a few implementations that used code that was pretty much identical. Which version of Laravel are you using?